# Regexp Get Text Between parenttheis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this:

```
var str = "Hello (World) I'm Newbie";
```

how to get `World` from string above using RegExp?, I'm sorry I don't understand about regex.

Thank's

Comment: @Barmar, I'm sorry for my question, I was chased by the time, so I didn't have time to read about regex, I was a beginner in the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a regex - use .split()...Note the escaped characters in the splits. The first split gives "World) I'm Newbie" and the second gives "World".

```js
var str = "Hello (World) I'm Newbie";

var strContent = str.split('\(')[1].split('\)')[0];
console.log(strContent); // gives "World"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there will be atleast one such word, you can do it using `String#match`. The following example matches the words between parentheses.

```js
console.log(
  "Hello (World) I'm Newbie"
  .match(/\(\w+\)/g)
  .map(match => match.slice(1, -1))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you for your regex

1. `\w` **match whole world**
2. `+` **plus with another regex**
3. `[]` **starts group**
4. `^` **except**
5. `(World)` **matching word**

```js
var str = "Hello (World) I'm Newbie";
var exactword=str.replace(/\w+[^(World)]/g,'')
var filtered = str.replace(/(World)/g,'') 
alert(exactword)
alert(filtered)
```